# How to write a scanner code to load what was previously saved in save.txt?

Tags: java, save, load

My goal is to load what is on the save.txt file. How would I write that? I am not sure if my write code is even writing to save.txt. Can you take a look?

```
else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysticker.length; i++){
        if (arraysticker[image]!=null){
            String name;
            int x,y;
            name = sticker.getname();
            x = sticker.getx();
            y = sticker.gety();
            fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This is one of my add "sticker" codes.

```
if (hatSoundPlay){ //if hatSoundPlay is true
    hatsound.play(); //and a hatsound will play
    sticker sticker1 = new sticker();//creates a new sticker1
    sticker1.arraysticker(hatPicture, "hat.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
    image ++;//increments image by 1
    arraysticker[image] = sticker1;//puts sticker 4 into the array
    sticker11 = true;
```

Comment: So it's space delimiter `String` (better hole that `name` doesn't contain spaces).  You might be able to use `String#split` to separate each element in a given line so you can reconstitute the `sticker` objects

Comment: this code doesn't save anything, since `FileWriter` needs to be flushed in order to save data to the file (`fw.flush()`).

Comment: I replaced fw.close() with fw.flush() but it still does not save. I open the save.txt but there is nothing in there after I click the save button.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < arraysticker.length; i++){
    if (arraysticker[image]!=null){
        String name;
        int x,y;
        name = sticker.getname();
        x = sticker.getx();
        y = sticker.gety();
        fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
    }
}
**fw.flush();
fw.close();**
```